# How to adjust the height for fadeInUp in ng-animate or Animate.css?

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, animate.css

This may be a very simple question for most of you, but I'm having a very difficult time figuring this out.

I have a data table that's big enough to run the entire screen. It's very specific so pagination is out of question. The issue that I'm having is with animation. I have the table inside div with ng-view. I want fadeInUp animation such that the fadeInUp seems to be from around 60-100px from the top. However, the current fadeInUp comes sliding up from the bottom of the screen which I do not want. How can I make it so that it slides up from the desired height?

`<div ng-view class="content-wrapper ng-fadeInUp">`

`[ng-view].ng-enter{
    animation:fadeInUp 1s;

}`

This is what's making it slide up from the bottom of the screen. I tried using "Animate.css" which did the same thing. I want it so that it seems it's barely sliding up. Just a small hint of animation instead of the full slide up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the [original](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/source/fading_entrances/fadeInUp.css) CSS from example animate.css and modify it:

```
@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.fadeInUp {
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

Change the second parameter in `translate3d` to what you want, for example:

```
transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/W5zsmhYkwXxYJbuft5pu?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed.